# ExactTarget and Radian6 for Social Customer Service

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have just downloaded the ExactTarget Dev org. and I would like to know how to get the Radian6 hub so that I can start testing the Social Customer Service into my Salesforce org.

Having this information that I am dying to get for the past two months would mean a lot to me since I am taking the Service Cloud certification very soon?

Thank you in advance.
Sandrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandrine,
The Radian6 hub does not have the same developer org option that Exact Target has. It is an add-on product (and very expensive too!). For the service cloud certification, I can guarantee that Radian6 will not be on it. The social customer service they refer to in the certification guide is actually an older option. If anything, there might be a question or two and it would likely be something about why it's important to have a social presence. Everything you need for that exam should be in the study guide. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was indeed worried since I saw a video about it and I was wondering if they would talk about it. Now you have cleared my mind. Cheers,